# SQL Sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document VIEW SELECT Permissions Not Working

Tags: function, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, system, user-permissions

I am making use of FULL Text search and I have implemented it by creating a full text catalog and full text index. In order to satisfy the requirement of showing number of occurences of the search keyword I want to access this dynamic management function 
dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document (DB_ID('DBNAME'),OBJECT_ID('TABLENAME')) which provides the display term from the file content and its number of occurences.

SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document (DB_ID('DBNAME'),OBJECT_ID('TABLENAME'))

This query statement gets executed without any errors and issues when I ran it by logging in with the login id 'sa' but its failing when i ran it with the user id.

I did try giving SELECT Permissions using

GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE

But no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280607.aspx states for sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document:

> Requires SELECT permission on the columns covered by the full-text index and CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG permissions.

Assuming the user in question already has `SELECT` permission you still need to

```
GRANT CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG TO userid
```